# Draw the bar's value in the bar

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

When I create a stacked bar chart, values of the bars are written at he top of their bar.
Is it possible to write these values in the middle of the bar ?

What I have :

```
 4
 _ 
| |
| |
| |
```

What I want :

```
 _ 
| |
|4|
| |
```

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: There is no code to show, I just create a Bar Chart with the library PMAndroidChart, and by default value of bar are written at the top of the bar. I want to know if it's possible to change this default characteristic.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the code on the github of the library to see if there are any methods you can call on the chart that you could use

Comment: I didn't find any method which give me this possibility, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**It's possible** to draw the value inside the bar.

Call `barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false)` to draw the value inside the bar.

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda How do you centre the value once it's inside the bar?

Comment: Is it possible to rotate the value too in this way?

Comment: @edwoollard, just wanted to check in if you found a way to center the value in the bar. please share..

Comment: @Sanniv I didn't ever actually find a way to centre the value in the bar. I ended up having to draw the value above the bar and then use a 'YOffset' in order to position it slightly inside each bar.

Comment: @edwoollard , how have you handled it , because when the bar height is small the text is overlapping the labels of x axis